# What are the skin types in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I try to create AVD in Android Studio, there are various skin types available like, **HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400**
I don't know what these skin types are, please explain what skin type is to be used while creating AVD.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This table shows the emulator skins that are available in the Android SDK, which you can use to emulate some of the most common screen configurations.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

[image]